# Duplicate a span without Clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm creating an ingredients app that has a form that looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/PZjfT/

As you can see, there is a `span` containing 2 textfields, and a select. You can delete any span by clicking on the X next to it.

My problem is that I'm using jQuery Clone, so if you delete all of the spans, then click "Add Ingredient", there is no divs to clone, so it doesn't add an ingredient.

How could I fix this? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Either prevent deletion of the last ingredient, or save the span in a variable or localStorage

Comment: or create a new span `$("<span/>").append($("<input/>")).append($("<input/>"))` and use .attr() to set the attributes as you create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for your last div, so you don't lose it.

[`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) will let you remove your last div from the DOM and save it in a variable, so you can later insert it again or clone from it.

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix, clone the element on document ready but don't put it into the page and use that to clone.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dmaQ/)

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myClone = $('#ingredientsCOUNT > span:first').clone();

        $('#btnAddIngredients').click(function () {
            var num = $('#ingredientsCOUNT span').length;
            var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
            myClone
                .clone()
                .attr('name', 'ingredient' + newNum)
                .appendTo('#ingredientsCOUNT')
                .fadeIn();
        });
        $('.formelementcontainer').on('click', '.deleteThis', function () {
            var span = $(this).closest('span');
            console.log(span);
            span.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                span.remove();
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be that you don't let the user delete the last `div`.

So you always start out with one ingredient `div` on the page.  Let them add new ones by cloning.

When the user removes an ingredient, delete the `div` and check how many ingredients are left.  If it is only one, remove or hide the delete button, so they can't delete the last ingredient.

Comment: But what happens when a user doesn't want any ingredients?

Comment: @Muhambi - Use `.detach()` to remove the div.